# How to get the docx in the iframe with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe

I want to get the document in the url such as below:

[document in the iframe](http://www.ibodao.com/OfficePreview?furl=/Public/uploads/files/2020/0219/5e4cc551729af.docx)

Try with wget command ,the downloaded file contain no document.
The document contained in the webpage can't be printed in pdf file in chrome.
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
target_doc_url = "http://www.ibodao.com/OfficePreview?furl=/Public/uploads/files/2020/0219/5e4cc551729af.docx"
driver.get(target_doc_url)
iframeMsg = driver.find_element_by_id("office_iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframeMsg);
with open('/tmp/target.html','w') as writer:
    writer.write(driver.page_source)
```

Open the `/tmp/target.html`,no document in it.
How to get the document in the iframe whose id is `office_iframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

target_doc_url = "http://www.ibodao.com/OfficePreview?furl=/Public/uploads/files/2020/0219/5e4cc551729af.docx"
driver.get(target_doc_url)
iframeMsg = driver.find_element_by_id("office_iframe")
src=iframeMsg.get_attribute("src")
m = re.search('.*?url=(.+?)/vector-output', src)
doc = m.group(1)
print(doc)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(doc, "a.docx")
```

this will save document as docx file , the src attribute in iframe shows the actual document file you don't need the vector-output part from the source

You can manually download it by going to :

http://static.ibodao.com/Public/uploads/files/2020/0219/5e4cc551729af.docx

Comment: iframeMsg.get_attribute("src")  contains the url.

Comment: @showkey yes thats what we are doing in code ,getting that and removing the vector-token part

Answer (score 0):

Make it more simple after getting the src which contains real url:

```
target_url = src.split("=")[1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(target_url, "target.docx")
```